# How to access value of variable in one custom directive in another custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made 2 custom directives and I use them in any HTML code like this

`<div textbox-component > </div>
<div grid-component ></div>`

The first one renders a textbox and a button .When we click on button it returns an Object.I want to pass that object onto the second directive which takes the object and makes a table of it.Is it possible by any way in Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use property on `$scope` that's shared from the parent scope.
I'm using a controller here as the parent scope:

```
module.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = {};
});

module.directive('textboxComponent', function() {
return {
    ...
    scope: {
        sharedObj: '=' 
    },

    link: function($scope) {
        $scope.doSomething = function() {
            $scope.sharedObj.test = 'hello world!'.  
        }
    }
};
});

// same definition using `scope` for gridComponent
```

And now you set that scope object:

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
    <div textbox-component shared-obj="bar">
        let us assume what follows inside is the template of this component

        <a ng-click="doSomething()">click me</a>
    </div>
    <div grid-component shared-obj="bar">
        let us assume what follows inside is the template of this component

        {{sharedObj.test}}
    </div>
</div>
```

In the link function of `gridComponent` you can also do this if you need to know when `sharedObj` changes from outside (another directive):

```
$scope.$watch('sharedObj', function() {
    console.log($scope.sharedObj.test);
}, true);
```

You could also use `$broadcast` but that's plain wrong in this context...